# javascript parameter passing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not quite sure how to describe what I want, but here goes nothing.

I am trying to have multiple buttons that will show/hide a div (I have that part set up already). I would like the button to have two values (number and letter) that will then fill in a parameter for another button's `onclick` event (these need to change however depending on what button was originally clicked.

For example, I click button1 which has values a and 1. This then fills in the parameters for the `onclick` event for button 3. Or I can click button 2 which has b and 2 and this will fill in b and 2 for the parameters for button 3 (so button 3 on click parameters need to change)

```
<input type='button' value="1" id="1" name="1" onclick="toggle();" style="background-color:lightblue; height:75px; width:75px;-webkit-appearance: none; border-radius: 70px;
" />
```

That button is what needs to have the two "values" of some sort
       Hamburger

That's the button that needs the values passed to the event.

```
var toggle = function() {
    var mydiv = document.getElementById('table1');
    if (mydiv.style.display === 'block' || mydiv.style.display === '')
        mydiv.style.display = 'none';
    else
        mydiv.style.display = 'block'
}
```

Comment: Post your html and js please.

Comment: that's the thing...I don't really have anything as I don't even know where to get started at.  I guess really the only HTML I have is just a basic button with an onclick event.  and JS is just the show hide code.  I'll go ahead a post that but not sure if it will really help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like some having the function set some global variables would do the trick. Not entirely sure of what you're trying accomplish:

You can pass whatever parms you want to toggle:

```html
<input type='button' value="1" id="1" name="1" onclick="toggle(1, a)" />
```

And then set them as global vars in in your JS:

```js
var parm1, parm2;

var toggle = function(myChar, myInt) {
  parm1 = myChar;
  parm2 = myInt;
}
```